# What happens on error with the connection to my postgres database? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I use `node-postgres` to connect to my postgres database. What happens if my SQL-Query fails? Do I have to close the connection manually (`client.end()`) or does Postgres closes this automatically?
Normally, I manually close the connection but I wonder if this is only necessary when successfuly querying my database.

Thanks
Lukas

Comment: The transaction is rolled back and enters a rolled back (failed) state. The connection is still active.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how your structure is and how often DB calls will happen.

If you have a server that gets multiple requests and do DB actions it is good use `pool` so you connect the DB on server init and destroy your connection on when server dies. You don't need to make extra connection, node-postgres pool will arrange it. Within the pool structure you don't need to cancel the connection event your query fails. Pool will manage that.

If you a single functions like lambdas it is wise to manage connection manually. So everytime function gets called you create connection and when the function does its job you destroy connection. In this way you need to make sure to catch the errors on global level and destroy connection manually. a `.finally()` statement would be helpful.